# Esp32 heating slowly

Tags: power, esp32, electronics

I made a small little IoT device to control my light chains from my phone, I'm using a MOSFET to turn the power on or off, using an esp32 connected to the MOSFET, both esp32 and light chain is supplied from a standard 6v phone charger I just clipped the wires and used it,

I have a voltage regulator on the esp32 as seen on the image, when I run the system the esp32 slowly heats up to around 40-50 Celcius, and I can hear a small whinny sound from the chip, the esp32 is getting 3.3v as I should when I measure with a multimeter

what's wrong?

(btw it works with turning lights on and off, not sure if those was the resisters i used)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that a map of where the nearest starbucks is? If it's supposed to be a schematic it's completely meaningless and impossible to read.

Comment: lol, ye sorry I didn't really know any good side to make the schematic on, didn't think it was that important, just wanted to give a general idea of what the circuit was

Comment: The question editor also has the function to draw schematics in it. Just click at the "Schematics" button (the one with the little schematic diagram) in the question editor and then you can create a proper schematic, which will directly tie into your question.

Comment: There's a schematic editor available right from the editor with *Ctrl-M*.

Comment: Did you build the regulator circuit or is it a pre-built module?

Comment: What is connected to what? Are you running your light chain from the output of your voltage regulator? What is the output voltage of the regulator? How are you powering the ESP32? If the voltage regulator is putting out 5V and you're using that to power your light chain and as VIN to your ESP32,  the ESP's voltage regulator is still having to drop 5V down to 3.3. That shouldn't generate a lot of heat unless you are drawing significant current from the ESP's regulator.

Comment: My **guess** is that the phone charger is a bit crappy, and doesn't produce a very stable voltage. I'd try adding a large bulk capacitor between the 6V and GND, to try to lower the, so called, noise.

Comment: The esp module has no components on it that can produce sound continuously. Ceramic capacitors can do so when the get ac voltage, but in your case the only ac is the 3.3V line's ripple. Buck converters often make a sound (coil whine). Are you really sure the sound is coming from the esp? 40-50° is not uncommon for an esp when wifi is enabled

Comment: after further research I have found out the sound came from the phone charger, probably just the transformer in it, still a bit worried about the temperature since I have never experienced temperature going up because of wifi use